# AWS : Any products to automate HTTP posting until correct response?

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, automation, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible using any of *Amazon Web Services* products to have posts scheduled at an interval to a specified endpoint. E.g. to check if a message queue has any items?

If a JSON response says OK then try again in 5 minutes?

Comment: this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html  ?

Comment: Also, I suggest you checkout Lamda + Dynamo DB (+triggers for Lamda) much more efficient than polling. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/wt-ddb.html